# How does react render multiple pages in app.js using react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create a multi-page react application. Is react-router right way to go?

Since there is only one HTML file named, **index.HTML** that pulls the rendered jsx code from **app.js**'s component. And even though we can have the feel of multiple page using react-route; technically isn't it only one-page application that react creates?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowerRoute as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/About';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Contact from './components/News';
import './App.css'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
       <Router>
        <div>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
        <Route path='/news' component={News} />
        <div> 
      </Router>
      
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Doesn't this mean all the pages must be rendered and loaded before displaying specific page? or am I wrong?

Is there a better way?

Comment: react-router and react are clever enough to not load things that are not needed. Usually your bundler will generate multiple chunks of Javascript to optimize page load. The only component that will be rendered will be the one that matches the current path. Each path based on your routing setup will effectively be a separate page that is loaded when the request is made. You will only ever have the one index file but I don't really see what the problem is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React is a Single Page Application (SPA) frontend framework. An intuitive definition of what this means is that your web app needs only 1 page load. However, an SPA can support the user experience of having "multiple pages", including changing the url path: e.g. www.app.com/home -> www.app.com/about. That is what the react router offers, the ability to associate different url paths to react components (www.app.com/home renders the `Home` component).

The underlying principle of SPAs is that instead of serving a new page, only one html page is served and the framework handles all UI changes via direct DOM manipulation.

> Doesn't this mean all the pages must be rendered before the HTML loads
>   the page? or am I wrong?

No, only the component associated to particular route/url-matcher will be rendered at any given time.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, keep with React Router.

Nops, only the page/component route that match the router path will be rendered.

But let me clarify it...

When you say:

> all the pages must be rendered before the HTML loads

I believe you mean loaded (the website/app files) and not rendered.

Render means that the route page/component will exist in DOM. So, loaded yes, rendered nope.

You can optimize it using [React Code-Splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) and/or playing with [Webpack Split Chunks](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/).

Comment: If all the pages are loaded at once, doesn't it mean heavy web applications can take longer time to load? Isn't it a downside? Is there a better way to load the page?

Comment: Check the links I sent to you about the React Code-Splitting and the Webpack Split Chunks.

Depending on your project, using import() might be the simplest / quickest way to get started.

`When Webpack comes across this syntax, it automatically starts code-splitting your app. If you’re using Create React App, this is already configured for you and you can start using it immediately. `